# Xamarin Forms - WebViewSource shows blank page

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms

I have `index.html` and `Posts1 - 10.html` inside a folder called `CachedPosts` inside `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)`. My goal is to load `index.html` which has href links to load `Posts1 - 10.html`.

You may tell me to use the Assets folder, but.. `Posts1 - 10.html` & `index.html` are being saved programmatically.

`C# Code`:

[image: C# Code]

So my issue lies in the "else" area.

`index.html` loads, but whenever I click on the href link inside `index.html`, it loads a blank page :/

`index.html Code`:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="Posts1.html"><h2>Interesting Stuff 1</h2></a>
<a href="Posts2.html"><h2>Interesting Stuff 2</h2></a>
</body>
</html>
```

`The Posts Code`:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Title: Posts Title</h1>
<p>So this is my first interesting post</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the Forms' Android `WebView` renderer and without re-writting it to properly support multi-mode content which you would need for a progressive web app, React hosting, etc..., you can "just" supply a URL for the initial page and not use the HtmlWebViewSource/BaseUrl at all if you have a simple caching routine.

This means that the first page loaded has to come from your cache location, along with all other content that those pages refer to so if you are dynamically creating any pages, including that first one, they need to be saved into the cache first.

If you are on Android, you could use Uri.Builder:

```
var url = new Android.Net.Uri.Builder()
                            .Scheme("file")
                            .Authority("localhost")
                            .AppendEncodedPath(CacheDir.CanonicalPath)
                            .AppendEncodedPath("index.html")
                            .Build();
```

Or just hard-code it via format string via:

```
$"file://localhost/{cacheDir}/index.html"
```

or

```
$"file:///{cacheDir}/index.html" // skip localhost is it is implied
```

And use the resulting url with a `UrlWebViewSource`:

```
webViewSource = new UrlWebViewSource { Url = $"file:///{cacheDir}/index.html" };
```